# Simple way to read / write to / from ListView in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, listview, io

Is there a simple / standard way to read from a file into a listview and save from a listview to a file? I really don't care if it's a TXT file, a XAML file or a binary file. It's not important and I don't have that much data.

Here are the columns and the data stored in each

```
    public class LVData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string YoungPic { get; set; }
        public string MediumPic { get; set; }
        public string AdultPic { get; set; }
        public bool SaltWater { get; set; }
        public bool FreshWater { get; set; }
        public bool Grasslands { get; set; }
        public bool Swamp { get; set; }
        public bool TropicalForrest { get; set; }
        public bool Forest { get; set; }
        public bool ForestEdge { get; set; }
        public bool Sand { get; set; }
        public bool Coastal { get; set; }
        public bool RiverBorder { get; set; }
        public bool LakeBorder { get; set; }
        public bool Floodplain { get; set; }
    }
```

My listview is named listView1.

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DinosaurIsland.PlantDisplay"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DinosaurIsland"
Title="Vegetation" Height="308" Width="1212" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="YoungPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding YoungPic}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MediumPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding MediumPic}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AdultPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding AdultPic}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TerrainCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <CheckBox Content="Salt Water"  Name="SaltWaterCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Saltwater}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Fresh Water"  Name="FreshWaterCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Freshwater}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Grassland / Plains"  Name="GrasslandsCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding Grassland}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Swamp"  Name="SwampCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Swamp}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Tropical Forest"  Name="TropicalForestCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding TropicalForest}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Forest"  Name="ForestCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Forest}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Forest Edge"  Name="ForestEdgeCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding ForestEdge}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Sand"  Name="SandCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Sand}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Coastal"  Name="CoastalCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Coastal}" />
            <CheckBox Content="River Border"  Name="RiverBorderCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding RiverBorder}" />
            <CheckBox Content="LakeBorder"  Name="LakeBorderCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding LakeBorder}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Floodplain"  Name="FloodplainCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding Floodplain}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PlacePlantsCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Margin="10"  Content="Random" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
            <Slider Margin="10"  Width="190" Value="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="100" TickPlacement="BottomRight"  TickFrequency="5"> </Slider>
            <Button Margin="10"  Content="Randomly Seed Plants" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="23" Name="SeedButton" ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="listView1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="152" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Picture of Young Plant" CellTemplate="{StaticResource YoungPicCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Picture of Medium Plant" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MediumPicCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Picture of Adult Plant" CellTemplate="{StaticResource AdultPicCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Terrain / Environments" CellTemplate="{StaticResource TerrainCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Place Plants" CellTemplate="{StaticResource PlacePlantsCell}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="New Plant"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,240,0,0" Name="NewPlant" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="NewPlant_Click" />
        <Button Content="Save" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"   Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1099,240,15,0" Name="SavePlant" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="SavePlant_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Load" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,240,0,0" Name="LoadPlants" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Click="LoadPlants_Click" Width="75" /> 
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

And here is a picture of the entire form/dialog box/listview (whatever it's called):
[Listview image http://dinosaur-island.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Seeding-Plants.jpg](http://dinosaur-island.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Seeding-Plants.jpg)

I've also added a 'Load' button since this screen cap was taken.

Comment: You could bind directly to a xml-File: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26875/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding So you wouldn't have to copy it to your file manuelly, you just have to save this file.

Comment: what?? Your question is completely unclear. And yes, you can store your data in whatever data storage you want, and that by itself has absolutely NOTHING to do with WPF or any presentation layer / UI element / whatever.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I'm confused about is how do I write each item in a listview to a file and then read it back? Is there a 'standard' way of doing this? I suppose I could just dump each row as a string to a txt file and then reverse the process for loading. I was looking for something more elegant. Couldn't find an example or any indication that this was the 'right' way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a small project to read data from XML and show it in a `ListView`.

Following is the sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Name>Dave</Name>
    <YoungPic>Picture1</YoungPic>
    <MediumPic>Picture2</MediumPic>
    <AdultPic>Picture3</AdultPic>
    <Terrain>1</Terrain>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Rachael</Name>
    <YoungPic>Picture1</YoungPic>
    <MediumPic>Picture2</MediumPic>
    <AdultPic>Picture3</AdultPic>
    <Terrain>2</Terrain>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

XAML code with two way binding ListView

```
<Window x:Class="lvs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lsvData, Mode=TwoWay}"   
        Name="listview1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,63" Width="262">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=YoungPic}" Header="Young Pic" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MediumPic}" Header="Medium Pic" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AdultPic}" Header="Adult Pic" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Terrain}" Header="Terrain" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Load" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,0,0,12" Name="Load" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="146" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="224,0,0,12" Name="Save" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="128" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Following is the code for Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private WindowViewModel _wvm;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _wvm = new WindowViewModel();
            this.DataContext = _wvm;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _wvm.PopulateData();
        }
    }
```

Then add the following two classes - Viewmodel and lsvData in the same project namespace

```
public class LVData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string YoungPic { get; set; }
        public string MediumPic { get; set; }
        public string AdultPic { get; set; }
        public byte Terrain { get; set; }
    }
    public class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        //called when a property is changed
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<LVData> _personList = new ObservableCollection<LVData>();
        public ObservableCollection<LVData> lsvData
        {
            get { return _personList; }
            set { _personList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("lsvData"); }
        }

        public void PopulateDataFromXML()
        {
            XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"c:\documents and settings\bjasti\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\lvs\lvs\data.xml");

            var Persons = from x in loaded.Descendants("Person")
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = x.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
                              YoungPic = x.Descendants("YoungPic").First().Value,
                              MediumPic = x.Descendants("MediumPic").First().Value,
                              AdultPic = x.Descendants("AdultPic").First().Value,
                              Terrain = x.Descendants("Terrain").First().Value
                          };
            foreach (var _person in Persons)
            {
                _personList.Add(new LVData { Name = _person.Name, YoungPic = _person.YoungPic, MediumPic = _person.MediumPic, AdultPic = _person.AdultPic, Terrain = Convert.ToByte(_person.Terrain) });
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("lsvData");
        }

    }
```

Check this solution and let me know if it works

Comment: First: thanks for all the help! I've almost got it. I've had to change the Terrain data. It's now a series of bools (for check boxes): `public class LVData
        {
           -snip-
            public bool SaltWater { get; set; }
            public bool FreshWater { get; set; }
            public bool Grasslands { get; set; }
            public bool Swamp { get; set; }
            public bool TropicalForrest { get; set; }
            public bool Forest { get; set; }
            public bool ForestEdge { get; set; }
            - etc. -
        }` How would this change your code?

Comment: Are the checkboxes mutually exclusive?

Comment: No, the checkboxes are NOT mutually exclusive. These are for plants and a plant 'type' can be in various different terrains. You can check as many terrain types as you want for each plant. FYI: here's a link to the entire project: http://dinosaur-island.com/wordpress/

Comment: How do I set the checkboxes from the XAML? How do I bind all the terrain type checkboxes?

Comment: Also, the file string of the image name is being displayed now, not the image. What do I need to change?

Comment: It's crashing on this line:  SaltWater = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.SaltWater) });

Comment: I've moved this over to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068300/populating-a-listview-with-checkboxes-from-a-xaml-file